# Plotting a cube on top of a plane, given all the vertices of the cube

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I am tring to plot a cube on top of a plane using matplotib.

I am doing a project on UAV(An unmanned aerial vehicle) Landing and there are these tests i have to visualize. I have a landing plane already plotted as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

xs = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
ys = np.linspace(-10, 20, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, zs)
Z = 0 / X

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_ylim([-40, 40])
ax.set_zlim([0, 10])
ax.set_xlim([-10, 10])
# Hide grid lines
# ax.grid(False)
plt.xlabel("X axis")
plt.ylabel("Y axis")

# Hide axes ticks
# ax.set_xticks([])
# ax.set_yticks([])
# ax.set_zticks([])
# plt.savefig("foo.png")
plt.show()
```

and the output is the following image.

[image: a landing strip for the UAV]

now i want to plot a cube inside the figure. I have a function that generates all the vertices points of a cube but i am running into errors trying to plot it. The vertices are generated from top-Northwest,top-NorthEast,top-Southeast, top-south west. the same applies for bottom.

Here is the function.

```
def createVertices(c3, stepSize):
    hs = 0.5 * stepSize
    a = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]+hs]
    b = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]+hs]
    c = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]+hs]
    d = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]+hs]
    e = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]-hs]
    f = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]-hs]
    g = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]-hs]
    h = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]-hs]
    
    return [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

I have to do this dynamically as I have over 100 testcases. Any help will be much appreciated.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Jared suggested [almost similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540109/plot-surfaces-on-a-cube) but I run into an error  `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'` coming from `ax.plot_surface(X,Y,1, alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot surfaces on a cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540109/plot-surfaces-on-a-cube)

Comment: Did you have a specific question? What did you try and what were you expecting?

Comment: I tried Jared's option and got `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'` coming from `ax.plot_surface(X,Y,1, alpha=0.5)` .

Comment: Yes, I have a specific question. I am trying to plot a 2D-like plane and a 3D cube on the same figure

Comment: @wanjaswilly Look at the answer more closely, you cannot pass `Z=1`,  you need to pass an array. And in your case, you might not want the plane at 1 but at a different value. For now, you can try and get it working with a unit cube.

Comment: @jared I solved for z while plotting the plane with `Z = 0 / X` which will evaluate to a `0 ndim`. My issue is to add a cube to the above image

Comment: @wanjaswilly I know, but your error showed that you wrote `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, 1, alpha=0.5)` and I don't think you can just put a 1 for the `Z` portion, you need an array. The error is saying that it is trying to do `1.ndim` and `1` is an `int` which doesn't have that attribute. If it is an array, then it would work fine. That's why the linked answer uses a `ones` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Matplotlib third-party package, [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/), has predefined cubes, just using that to get:

[image: Cubes on a plane]

where the code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

# test cases ......
stepSize = [ 3, 6, 1, 4 ]
centers = [ [5,20,6] , [-7,7,7] , [1,1,1], [0,-30,5] ]
colors = [ 'C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C4']

shade=False  #......................  set True to show solid cubes
for i, ss in enumerate(stepSize) :
    surf = s3d.CubicSurface(0,color=colors[i]).domain( ss/2, ss/2, ss/2 )
    surf.transform(translate=centers[i])
    surf = surf.shade() if shade else surf.edges  
    boxes = surf if i==0 else boxes+surf

landing = s3d.PlanarSurface(0,color='.6').domain(10,10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set( xlim = [-10,10], ylim=[-40,40],  zlim=[0,10],
        xlabel='X',      ylabel='Y',     zlabel='Z' )
ax.add_collection3d(landing)
ax.add_collection3d(boxes)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It appears from the `createVertices` function, the cube center coordinates and widths are passed in, so just directly used those.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve for creating the cube dynamically. Here is the whole script.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

# create an array of all cube's center points
xPoints = np.linspace(30,50,3, dtype = int)
yPoints = np.linspace(-20,20,5, dtype = int)
zPoints = np.linspace(5,35,7, dtype = int)

allPoints= []

for xp in xPoints:
    for yp in yPoints:
        for zp in zPoints:
            allPoints.append([xp,yp,zp])

# plot each of the cube
for c3 in allPoints:
    # figure name
    figName = ""+str(c3[0])+"_"+str(c3[1])+"_"+str(c3[2])+".pdf"
    
    # landing strip
    xs = np.linspace(10, 60, 100)
    ys = np.linspace(-10, 20, 100)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
    Z = 0 / X

    # create vertices
    hs = 0.5 * 2
    a = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]+hs]
    b = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]+hs]
    c = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]+hs]
    d = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]+hs]
    e = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]-hs]
    f = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]+hs,c3[2]-hs]
    g = [c3[0]+hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]-hs]
    h = [c3[0]-hs,c3[1]-hs,c3[2]-hs]

    # arrange the vertices
    vertices =  [h,g,c,d,e,f,b,a]

    x, y, z = [],[],[]
    for vert in vertices:
        x.append(vert[0])
        y.append(vert[1])
        z.append(vert[2])

     # Face IDs
    vertices = [[0,1,2,3],[1,5,6,2],[3,2,6,7],[4,0,3,7],[5,4,7,6],[4,5,1,0]]
    tupleList = list(zip(x, y, z))

    poly3d = [[tupleList[vertices[ix][iy]] for iy in range(len(vertices[0]))] for ix in range(len(vertices))]

    # finally some plotting ;-)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(x,y,z)
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(poly3d, facecolors='r', linewidths=1, alpha=0.5))
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    ax.set_ylim([-40, 40])
    ax.set_zlim([0, 40])
    ax.set_xlim([0, 60])
    
    # Hide grid lines
    # ax.grid(False)
    
    plt.xlabel("X axis")
    plt.ylabel("Y axis")
    plt.savefig(figName)
```

I hope it helps someone in future